# Class 'Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf' not found

Tags: laravel, pdf

Sou iniciante em Laravel. Peguei um sistema legado com as seguintes configurações:
Laravel 3.2.12 e PHP 5.6. Este sistema usa o DOMPDF. Contudo, não consegue gerar um dos arquivos html devido ao tamanho. Por conta disso, fiz a instalação via composer Html2Pdf. Mas sempre apresenta o erro Class 'Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf' not found. O que estou fazendo de errado?

```````````````````````````````````````````
use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

$html = View::make('template.pdf.relatorio-consolidado-pc', compact(
        'formato',
            'projeto',
            'pc');
$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf('P','A4','pt');
            $html2pdf->writeHTML($html);
            $pdf = $html2pdf->Output('relatorio-projeto-esportivo');

 return response ($pdf);
``````````````````````````````````````````
```````````````````````````````````````````

Answer (score 0):

Tenta seguir esse modelo, adicione o require do autoload ao seu código.

```
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Spipu\Html2Pdf\Html2Pdf;

$html2pdf = new Html2Pdf();
$html2pdf->writeHTML('Olá, isso é um teste!');
$html2pdf->output();
```

Comment: Não deu certo. Aparece o seguinte erro: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\incentivo-php\application\controllers\prestacaocontas/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Essa mensagem diz que o arquivo ou o diretório não existe, possa ser que C:\xampp\htdocs\incentivo-php\application\controllers\prestacaocontas/vendor/autoload.php não seja o caminho correto.